# How do I return an error from a scoped_threadpool thread?

Tags: error-handling, rust

I have some code that uses [scoped_threadpool](https://crates.io/crates/scoped_threadpool) a bit like this:

```
extern crate scoped_threadpool;

use scoped_threadpool::Pool;
use std::error::Error;

fn main() {
    inner_main().unwrap();
}

fn inner_main() -> Result<(), Box<Error>> {
    let mut pool = Pool::new(2);

    pool.scoped(|scope| {
        scope.execute(move || {
            // This changed to become fallible
            fallible_code();
        });
    });

    Ok(())
}

fn fallible_code() -> Result<(), Box<Error + Send + Sync>> {
    Err(From::from("Failing"))
}
```

The `fallible_code` function recently changed to return a `Result`, and I'd like to propagate the error outside of the `pool.scoped` block. However, the signature of [`Scope::execute`](http://kimundi.github.io/scoped-threadpool-rs/scoped_threadpool/struct.Scope.html#method.execute) doesn't allow for a return value:

```
fn execute<F>(&self, f: F) 
    where F: FnOnce() + Send + 'scope
```

I am using scoped_threadpool 0.1.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it's a particularly idiomatic method, but one method that at least works is assigning to a captured variable.

```
let mut pool = Pool::new(2);
let mut ret = Ok(());

pool.scoped(|scope| {
    scope.execute(|| {
        ret = fallible_code();
    });
});

ret.map_err(|x| x as Box<Error>)
```

Obviously you'd need to make `ret` an `Option` or so if there is no trivial default. If the inner closure must be `move`, you'll need to make `ret_ref = &mut ret` explicit.

Comment: @MatthieuM. It is, which is why `ret.map_err(|x| x as Box<Error>)` is needed to match `inner_main`'s return type.